# How to use different base class in custom control depending on platform target?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-controls, multitargeting

I have a custom editor that I use for iOS, but for UWP I use another editor called `SfRichTextEditor`.

Now I wonder how I can create like a shareable class, since they have the same bindableproperties instead of doing what I currently do, which is creating a `ContentView` on top of them, which is causing:

1. unnecessary nesting for performance purposes
2. duplicate code
3. seems to have trouble with some bindings (not verified, but something strange).

   ```
   <ContentView>
       <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
           <OnPlatform.Platforms>
               <On Platform="iOS">

                   <controls:CustomIOSEditor/>
               </On>
               <On Platform="UWP">
                   <controls:CustomUWPEditor/>
               </On>
           </OnPlatform.Platforms>
       </OnPlatform>
   </ContentView>
   ```

So instead of this approach, I want to have a shareable base class if possible, to reuse the code.

These are the x2 controls that I have today.

My iOS custom control:

```
public class CustomIOSEditor : Editor // Using regular xamarin editor
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty StringResultCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(StringResultCommand),
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(CustomIOSEditor),
            default(ICommand));

    public object StringResultCommandParameter
    {
        get => GetValue(StringResultCommandParameterProperty);
        set => SetValue(StringResultCommandParameterProperty, value);
    }
}
```

My UWP custom control:

```
public class CustomUWPEditor : SfRichTextEditor // Using SfRichTextEditor instead here.
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty StringResultCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(StringResultCommand),
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(CustomUWPEditor),
            default(ICommand));

    public object StringResultCommandParameter
    {
        get => GetValue(StringResultCommandParameterProperty);
        set => SetValue(StringResultCommandParameterProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Latest clue**
[image]
UPDATE**
Shared .csproj:
[image]

MacOS:
[image]

Settings:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: Check now. So it is the one i highlight, the first two u can ignore

Comment: Yes i did. Also restarted visual studio. Still the same issue.

Comment: I use xamarn forms btw.

Comment: Yes I know of course it XF (otherwise it doesn't make sense), .__MACOS__. seems working as expected and everything seems good in the code, sorry I have no idea for now.

Comment: Ok. I do not need to change anyhting MacOS specific?

Comment: No, when I implemented on my app (Android only) didn't have to change anything on native (Android) .csproj file

Comment: is it happening when you build/deploy against MacOS only or even with uwp?

Comment: okok. i think the macOS project is netstandard 2.0, and thus it might not work? but not sure if 2.1 works

Comment: havent tried UWP yet. i can try iOS in 30min to see.

Comment: Unfortunatley still having issues :/

Comment: But might've found a clue. See the image i uploaded.

Comment: You fixed the build error? Don't tell me the issue was because you had xf shared project as startup project?

Comment: Did not fix it no. i use a regular xam forms project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all code is common except the inheritance is different, it better to use a compile-time check (no worries of code being messy in this case).

Xamarin.Forms project does not support Multi-targeting frameworks, [at the opposite it next evolution which is called MAUI will](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/#xamarinforms-vs-net-maui).

Meanwhile you can use [**MSBuild SDK Extras**](https://github.com/novotnyllc/MSBuildSdkExtras) SDK instead of the default `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` an (but keep in mind that it is not officially supported), but end result is neat (compile-time check).

- In `YourSharedProject.csproj` change `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` to `<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras/2.1.2">`.
- Setup the platforms that your projects is targeting and their version:

Example if you target netstandard2.1 and iOS 10 then change `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.1;iOS10</TargetFrameworks>` by starting with the `netstandardxx` first.

- Taget Uwp: `<TargetFrameworks Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' ">$(TargetFrameworks);uap10.0.17763;netcoreapp3.1;net472</TargetFrameworks>` (if you have .net framework 4.7.1 installed instead of 4.7.2, replace `net472` by `net471` (same thing for .net.core and uwp versions).

At the end, your .csproj file starts will looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras/2.1.2">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.1;iOS10</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' ">
$(TargetFrameworks);uap10.0.17763;netcoreapp3.1;net472</TargetFrameworks>
```

All this will enable you to use the [symbolic constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/platform-divergence-abstraction-divergent-implementation#conditional-compilation) in a conditional compile time check:

```
public class CustomIOSEditor : 
#if __iOS__
           Editor     //will inherit from this if we are building against iOS
#endif
#if WINDOWS_UWP      //will inherit from this if we are building against uwp
           SfRichTextEditor
#endif
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty StringResultCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(StringResultCommand),
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(CustomIOSEditor),
            default(ICommand));

    public object StringResultCommandParameter
    {
        get => GetValue(StringResultCommandParameterProperty);
        set => SetValue(StringResultCommandParameterProperty, value);
    }
}
```

---

For targeting other platforms-version:

- Mac version 20: `Xamarin.Mac20`
- Android version 10.0: `MonoAndroid10.0`
- tizen version 40: `tizen40`

Comment: Oh wow thats very nice indeed. I will give it a go now to see if it works. Any idea if there are any known bugs (since it is not officially supported yet)?

Comment: Do you know what to type when it comes to macOS for instance?     <TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkIdentifier>Xamarin.Mac</TargetFrameworkIdentifier> this is the targetversion i find when digging into its .csproj

Comment: Indeed `Xamarin.Mac` + version appended without any space. I have updated my answer. For bugs you can always take a the repo I have linked and see /issues.

Comment: Hmm having issues. It takes the compiler like 20 sec to calculate that it is missing a Type, for the custom class. Not sure if its because xamarin mac is not 2.1. supported? I am not sure how i can make it 2.1 compatibable.

Comment: i test both -     <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.1;Xamarin.Mac20</TargetFrameworks>
and also     <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;Xamarin.Mac20</TargetFrameworks>

Comment: Hm i presume i also have it on the latest version ? Where could i check this? I am very new on developing for Xamarin.Mac

Comment: Could you share the error, maybe the issue is in your project? (to be honest I don't have any experience on Mac develpment..)

Comment: Check updated post to see the screenshots of issue + setup. And to explain error, i can press play, it builds for 20 sec, then it gives me the "Type expected (CS1031)" where the inherited class goes (not showing red though as u would expect the IDE to do)

Answer (score 0):

**What you are looking for is `SetNativeControl()`.**

Check this example for instance,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view#creating-the-custom-renderer-on-uwp

Pasting same sample from above link here

NOTE - `CameraPreview` in below sample is Xamarin.Form element and `CaptureElement` is a UWP control

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CameraPreview), typeof(CameraPreviewRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.UWP
{
    public class CameraPreviewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CameraPreview, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CaptureElement>
    {
        ...
        CaptureElement _captureElement;
        bool _isPreviewing;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CameraPreview> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe
                Tapped -= OnCameraPreviewTapped;
                ...
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                if (Control == null)
                {
                  ...
                  _captureElement = new CaptureElement();
                  SetupCamera();
                  SetNativeControl(_captureElement);
                }
            }
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't an overkill to use a custom renderer in this case ? I don't see how this will remedy to "duplicate code"?

Comment: Yeah, then i would have to write platform specific code for the platforms, i think there should be better ways to solve it.